# AppSettings for a .NET Core Project not overriding in Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

The appsetting for a .NET Core project can be overridden in Docker Container using the Environment variable. For Example

**Appsetting.json**

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug"
    }
}
```

**DockerFile** (Incase of Base OS as Ubuntu)

```
ENV Logging__LogLevel__Default "Warning"
```

**DockerFile** (Incase of Base OS as Windows)

```
ENV Logging:LogLevel:Default "Warning"
```

The above thing works perfectly fine for all my project but suddenly I find the configurations are not getting overridden using Docker file defined Environment Variables.

**The Probable Reason I can think of**
    - I created a Project of ASP.NET Core 3.0 and something broke in it.

Answer (score 4):

The Reason was surely not the ASP.NET Core migration but there was a mistake in using the Configuration builder. One need to specifically provide **config.AddEnvironmentVariables();** in **Program.cs** so that the environment variables could be **overwritten by the dockerfile**

It's a small reason but sometime it could hit hard as it not possible to debug it in a production environment and also debugging is quite hard with docker environment.

A good source to understand Environment Variable in .NET Core. Please Refer [here](https://andrewlock.net/why-isnt-my-asp-net-core-environment-specific-configuration-loading/)